# Compiling *.Rnw files with knitr --without Rstudio

Tags: r, vim, knitr

I would like to use `knitr` to create presentations that embed `R` objects and code.

For IT reasons I am restricted to vim, so i have found the available Rstudio+knitr examples fairly unhelpful.  The vim section of the `knitr` [documents](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/editors/) is also very skinny, and therefore unhelpful.

Is someone able to provide some guidance on how to compile a `*.Rnw` or `*.Rmd` file using `knitr` (or alternately point me to a decent online tutorial?) using some combination of `vim`, `R`, and the command line?

thanks in advance

Comment: The simplest case basically just goes `library(knitr); knit('my_input.Rnw')`. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: See http://yihui.name/knitr/

Comment: Great, thanks @Marius. That's the breakthrough i needed. I guess i had become blind from effort. I set out `myfile.Rnw` file as i would in Rstudio, saved it, and then executed `library(knitr); knit('myfile.Rnw')` in `R` -- worked a treat. If you'd like to give it as an answer i'll accept.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of going through Rstudio, you can use the functions in the `knitr` package directly. There are some options you can tweak, but to get started, all you have to do is call the `knit()` function on your `.Rnw` file:

```
library(knitr)
knit('my_input.Rnw')
```

If you're missing some of Rstudio's features, it's worth remembering that most of them are just making use of things that are already available in various R packages, so you can usually find a way to use them when you don't have Rstudio available.